# Validate struct field if it exists

Tags: go

I'm POSTing a JSON user object to my Golang application where I decode the 'req.body' into a 'User' struct.

```
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(user)
//handle err if there is one
```

and the 'User' struct:

```
type User struct {
    Name      string  `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Username  string  `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Email     string  `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Town      string  `json:"town,omitempty"`
    //more fields here
}
```

While I don't need help with the actual validation, I would like know how to validate usernames only if it is included as part of the JSON object. At the moment, if a username isn't included then `User.Username` will still exist but be empty i.e. `""`

**How can I check to see if '"username"' was included as part of the POSTed object?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why not check `if len(user.Username) == 0 { noUsername(); }`?

Comment: If a user object is posted without `username` then `len(user.Username)` will still equal 0. I want to conditionally validate - that is, I want to validate the username only if it was included in the POST object. Sorry if it's unclear!

Comment: So I need to be able to distinguish between a User object than contains a username with value `""` (i.e. username has been forgotten) and User object without a username.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a pointer to a string:

```
type User struct {
    Name     string  `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Username *string `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Email    string  `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Town     string  `json:"town,omitempty"`
    //more fields here
}

func main() {
    var u, u2 User
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"username":"hi"}`), &u)
    fmt.Println("username set:", u.Username != nil, *u.Username)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{}`), &u2)
    fmt.Println("username set:", u2.Username != nil)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/LpvXWh1m65)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know it could be done like this. I'm going to test in the morning and will tick then if it's all good!

Comment: I've got this going. Quick question - if I want to check the length of the `username` after I've checked whether it's `nil` do I need to de-reference it? e.g. `len(*user.Username)`

Comment: yes, the `len` function cannot take type `*string` as an argument. http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len

Comment: This Solution did not work for me. Still giving me ' Error:Field validation for 'Gstin' failed on the 'gstin' tag.

type PutBeneDto struct {
 Email     *string `json:"email"  validate:"email"`
 Gstin     *string `json:"gstin"  validate:"gstin,omitempty"`
}

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer. Note that the order of the validate functions is important. I was getting the error because I was placing the UUIDV4 validation tag before the omitempty:

```
ParentID    *string `json:"parent_id" validate:"uuid4,omitempty"`
```

Correct way is:

```
ParentID    *string `json:"parent_id" validate:"omitempty,uuid4"`
```