# Assign struct with another struct

Tags: struct, go

I have a RegistrationRequest struct:

```
type RegistrationRequest struct {
    Email    *string
    Email2   *string        
    Username *string
    Password *string
    Name     string
}
```

Where `Email2` is the email value entered again to verify that what the user entered is correct.

I also have a User struct:

```
type User struct {
    Email    *string
    Username *string
    Password *string
    Name     string           
}
```

Of course, there is no need to store `Email2` beyond registration.

So I have two variables: `req` and `u` - one for each struct. Is it possible to assign the `req` struct into to the `u` struct so that all the common fields will exist in the `u` struct?

Comment: you mean struct embedding?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using simple [assignment](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) you can't because even though the fields of `User` are a subset of `RegistrationRequest`, they are completely 2 different types, and [Assignability](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules don't apply.

You could write a function which uses reflection ([`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package), and would copy all the fields from `req` to `u`, but that is just ugly (and inefficient).

Best would be to refactor your types, and `RegistrationRequest` could [embed](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) `User`.

Doing so if you have a value of type `RegistrationRequest` that means you already also have a value of `User`:

```
type User struct {
    Email    *string
    Username *string
    Password *string
    Name     string
}

type RegistrationRequest struct {
    User  // Embedding User type
    Email2 *string
}

func main() {
    req := RegistrationRequest{}
    s := "as@as.com"
    req.Email = &s

    s2 := "testuser"
    req.Username = &s2

    u := User{}
    u = req.User
    fmt.Println(*u.Username, *u.Email)
}
```

Output: (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tL_fPDe0UK))

```
testuser as@as.com
```

Also please note that since your structs contain pointers, when copying a `struct`, pointer values will be copied and not pointed values. I'm not sure why you need pointers here, would be best to just declare all fields to be non-pointers.

Also note that embedding is not really a requirement, it just makes your types and their usage more smooth. `User` could just as well be an "ordinary" field of `RequistrationRequest`, e.g.:

```
type RegistrationRequest struct {
    Usr User // This is just an ordinary field, not embedding
    Email2 *string
}
```

Comment: NIce approach - this should work for me. Going to try it now.

Comment: Side question: The field `User` in the `RegistrationRequest` - does it "assume" the type is `User` as nothing is defined.

Comment: @tommyd456 Please read what [embedding](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) is. When embedding, only the _type_ is provided, but not the _name_. So `User` _is_ the type. And fields of `User` are _promoted_ to the embedder struct. But you can refer to the embedded value by using the type name.

Comment: I do know what embedding is. I've always provided both and it seems to work but I will read up on that too. I'm sure I've seen examples that use name and type.

Comment: @tommyd456 When you provide both the _name_ and the _type_, that is not embedding, that is just declaring a field. That may also be good for you.

Comment: Oh ok - perhaps I don't know what embedding is then ha ha

Comment: Regarding your last edit - pointers are required as I need to distinguish between JSON objects that don't contain the field `username` (for example) and JSON objects that do contain the field `username` but with a value `""` - see an older question of mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504975/validate-struct-field-if-it-exists

Comment: You can simply clone the User field with this statement
      u := req.User
without creating it before

Comment: @MaxZerbini Yes, you may do so. The question stated there are already 2 variables `req` and `u`, and I was trying to mimic that.

Comment: if RegistrationRequest contains common field from user will it overwrite or throw an error?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Then you will have 2 of that field. E.g. if `RegistrationRequest` would also have an `Email string` field, `req` would have to `Email` fields: one referred to as `req.Email`, and the other as `req.User.Email`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "[github.com/jinzhu/copier](https://github.com/jinzhu/copier)" package to Copy between structs containing same field name. This package uses reflection to do this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"  
    "github.com/jinzhu/copier"
)

type RegistrationRequest struct {
    Email    *string
    Email2   *string
    Username *string
    Password *string
    Name     string
}

type User struct {
    Email    *string
    Username *string
    Password *string
    Name     string
}

func main() {
    user := new(User)
    req := new(RegistrationRequest)
    user.Email, user.Password, user.Username = new(string), new(string), new(string)
    user.Name = "John Doe"
    *user.Email = "a@b.com"
    *user.Password = "1234"
    *user.Username = "johndoe"
    fmt.Println("User :",user.Name, *user.Email, *user.Username, *user.Password)
    copier.Copy(req, user)
    fmt.Println("RegistrationRequest :",req.Name, *req.Email, *req.Username, *req.Password)
}
```

Output

```
 User : John Doe a@b.com johndoe 1234
 RegistrationRequest : John Doe a@b.com johndoe 1234
```

Comment: This is much closer to what the OP requested.  Given the other answer, it might be useful to know whether copier works the same with embedded structs!

Answer (score 0):

```
func ObjectAssign(target interface{}, object interface{}) {
    // object atributes values in target atributes values
    // using pattern matching (https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590190/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-golang
    t := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    o := reflect.ValueOf(object).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < o.NumField(); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < t.NumField(); j++ {
            if t.Field(j).Name() == o.Field(i).Name() {
                t.Field(j).Set(o.Field(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second structure is a clone of the first one with fewer fields you can convert the structures via json.

```
type user1 struct {
 FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
 LastName string `json:"last_name"`
 UserName string `json:"user_name"` 
}

type user2 struct {
 FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
 LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}
```

...

```
u1Json, _ := json.Marshal(u1)
_ = json.Unmarshal(u1Json,&u2)
```