# Golang - conversion between structs

Tags: data-structures, go, casting

I have two structs

```
type A struct {
    a int
    b string
}

type B struct {
    A
    c string
    // more fields
}
```

I'd like to convert variable of type A to type B (A has defined only basic fields that are crucial for some parts, B on the other hand contains 'full' data).

Is it possible in Go, or do I have to copy fields manually (or create a method A.GetB() or something like this and use this to convert A to B)?

Comment: What does it mean to "convert" A.data to B.data?

Comment: Why do you need to convert a struct type into another struct type, when the embedded struct fields are accessible from the parent struct?

Comment: In C++ you could have A as the base class for B, and give a constructor to B that takes an A (you could even use *move semantics*). Is that possible in go too?

Comment: And I don't understand the downvote. This question is clear and backed up with code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign struct with another struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981592/assign-struct-with-another-struct)

Comment: @icza It's not a duplicate. Check my answer. Here, memory alignment of struct are a bit similar. In that question, struct is completely different.

Comment: I was thinking of something like a usual type conversion, e.g. []byte("string") and jussius' answer does exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By converting do you mean this:

```
func main() {
    // create structA of type A
    structA := A{a: 42, b: "foo"}

    // convert to type B
    structB := B{A: structA}
}
```

Comment: This is great solution, I don't know I was under an impression, that B.a will have different value that B.A.a after this assignment.

Answer (score -2):

The types `A` and `B` have different underlying types so they cannot be converted into each other. No way.

So either copy manually or provide converter functions or methods which do this copying.

Comment: This is wrong answer. Please delete it. B has A embedded in it.

Comment: No, the answer is correct. Type conversions are defined in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions. The relevant cases here are "identical underlying types" (which the do not have) and "assignable" which they are not (see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). The fact that B embeds A is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Yes, but you can convert using unsafe pointer here as layout is quite same. You don't need any function or something.

Comment: @khrm No, you cannot. You can't use `unsafe.Pointer` here because a value of type `A` has different memory layout than a value of type `B`. The size of `B` is bigger than the size of `A`, so after using a `*A` as `*B`, by changing the `B.c` field you might overwrite memory that belongs to other variables or maybe even that contains code. Don't do this under any circumstances!