# downcast higher-type to lower

Tags: go, struct, type-conversion, embedding

Is there beside copying the inner `Box` value by hand a language feature to down-cast `RatedBox` into a `Box`?

```
type Box struct {
    Name string
}

type RatedBox struct {
    Box
    Points int
}

func main() {
    rated := RatedBox{Box: Box{Name: "foo"}, Points: 10}

    box := Box(rated) // does not work
}
```

[go-playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iNpPgiIWqv)

```
// works, but is quite verbose for structs with more members
box := Box{Name: rated.Name}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang : Is conversion between different struct types possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613271/golang-is-conversion-between-different-struct-types-possible)

Comment: Can't you use. box := rated.Box ??

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725577/19020

Comment: @DanEsparza I fail to see how my question could be a duplicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) a type in a struct adds a field to the struct, and you can use the unqualified type name to refer to it (unqualified means omit the package name and the optional pointer sign).

For example:

```
box := rated.Box
fmt.Printf("%T %+v", box, box)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JCd4XNt2rC)):

```
main.Box {Name:foo}
```

Note that [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) copies the value, so the `box` local variable will hold a copy of the value of the `RatedBox.Box` field. If you want them to be the "same" (to point to the same `Box` value), use a pointer, e.g.:

```
box := &rated.Box
fmt.Printf("%T %+v", box, box)
```

But here of course type of `box` will be `*Box`.

Or you may choose to embed the pointer type:

```
type RatedBox struct {
    *Box
    Points int
}
```

And then (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HkVjCyb3e4)):

```
rated := RatedBox{Box: &Box{Name: "foo"}, Points: 10}

box := rated.Box
fmt.Printf("%T %+v", box, box)
```

Output of the last 2:

```
*main.Box &{Name:foo}
```

Comment: Go isn't object oriented in the same way C++ or Java is. For cases where you need polymorphism you should use interfaces. This answer is the best you can do without them.