# Transform struct into different struct before marshalling to JSON

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a boardgame using go as the backend, and have hit a bit of a blocker and am trying to understand what's the best way to solve this in the go way.

I have a complex struct that represents the state of the game which I use in my game engine, to evaluate the state and also what every action will do and how it will affect the game.

```
type Game struct {
    ID            string
    Name          string              `json:"name"`
    Version       Version             `json:"version"`
    StartingMode  StartingMode        `json:"startingMode"`
    Players       []*Player           `json:"players"`
    GameMap       *BoardMap           `json:"gameMap"`
    Countries     map[string]*country `json:"countries"`
    Config        *Config             `json:"config"`
    TurnPlayer    *Player             `json:"turnPlayer"`    //represents the player who started the turn
    TurnCountry   *country            `json:"turnCountry"`   //represents the country which started the turn
    CurrentPlayer *Player             `json:"currentPlayer"` //represents the current player to action
    GameStart    bool     `json:"gameStart"`
    GameFinish   bool     `json:"gameFinish"`
    InAuction    bool     `json:"inAuction"` //represents the game is in the auction stage
    GameSettings Settings `json:"settings"`
}
```

Now, I can marshal this to JSON and save it in my DB and it works fine, but when I have to send it to the front end, it does not really work. Also the front-end doesn't need to know that much information, I really would want something simpler like, for example:

```
type OtherGame struct {
 players []*OtherPlayer
 countries []*OtherCountry
 map []*OtherArea
}
```

So, I'm thinking I have to write some converter function and then marshal this OtherGame struct, or **should I just write a custom function that iterates to the different structs within Game and puts them into a string using Sprintf?**

Comment: Does this partially answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724757/golang-conversion-between-structs/37725577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this design pattern a lot to produce custom output for particular handlers. Define your JSON tags there and only expose what you need. The custom-type is then tightly coupled with your handler:

```
func gameHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    g, err := dbLookupGame(r) // handle err

    // define one-time anonymous struct for custom formatting
    jv := struct {
        ID      string `json:"id"`
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Version string `json:"ver"`
    }{
        ID:      g.ID,
        Name:    g.Name,
        Version: g.Version,
    }

    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&jv) // handle err
}

type game struct {
    ID      string
    Name    string
    Version string
    Secret  string // don't expose this
   // other internals ...
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hhAAlmb51Ue

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `method` that converts your `Game` data to `OtherGame`. Something like this.

```golang
func (game Game) OtherGame() OtherGame {
    return OtherGame{
        players:   game.Players,
        countries: game.Countries,
    }
}
```

Call this method just before sending to `front-end`.

```golang
game := Game{...}
otherGame := game.OtherGame()
```