# convert TypeA to TypeB where the underlying field types are the same

Tags: go, casting, converters

In my playground code there're 2 types shares very similar field definition like this,

```
type Int64 int64

type TA struct {
    A Int64
    B string
}

type TB struct {
    A int64
    B string
}
```

how can I convert between both with minimal code and perf cost?

https://play.golang.org/p/VFERyT-RgK

p.s. As tested, TA(some_tb_value) like above case will only work if TA.A is EXACTLY same typed with TB.A. However making the underlying type (Int64->int64) exactly the same doesn't fit the use case I needed.

p.s. Serialising some_tb_value with some protocol (json) and unserialising back to a TA typed pointer is possible, but it could be too heavy for critical path use

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Assign struct with another struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981592/assign-struct-with-another-struct)

Comment: @icza thanks for pointing out. reflect is possible solution. I'm looking if any other performant approach for a heavy use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are different struct types, you can't convert them.

One solution is to use reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to copy the fields.

And since they have the same memory layout, another solution is to use package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/):

```
func main() {
    var a TA = TA{1, "I'm TA"}
    var b TB = TB{2, "I'm TB"}
    fmt.Println(TA2TB(&a), TB2TA(&b))
}

func TA2TB(a *TA) *TB {
    return (*TB)(unsafe.Pointer(a))
}
func TB2TA(b *TB) *TA {
    return (*TA)(unsafe.Pointer(b))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XmkvlcZd_4)):

```
&{1 I'm TA} &{2 I'm TB}
```

But know that using `unsafe` you lose all type safety checks. If in the future the types get modified, the code will continue to compile but mystic errors may arise during runtime (runtime panic if you're lucky, silent misbehaving in worse case, and complete collapsing in worst case).

Best would be to refactor your code and use the same underlying types, so you could simply do a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Comment: Agree with refactoring. The real case behind it is my trying to fit native Go type (with many methods) to go-swagger where types are just primitive types, where I may really need this kind to convert. (just providing background)

Comment: hi @icza, to make this solution complete, any idea how to systematically verify two type share exactly same memory layout? People probably can run it offline / at playground to verify correctness before using this powerful cast in any serious deployment.