# change struct type in Go

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have two struct types

```
type type1 struct {
a1,b1,c1 string
}
type type2 struct {
a2,b2 string
}
```

and want to change type of variable p if  the condition is true. How I am supposed to do it in Go ? Below does not work. And I think the question **'Golang : Is conversion between different struct types possible?'** does not address this case because I am getting error *"cannot convert p .. cannot use type2 as type1 in assignment ...too many values in struct initializer"*

```
var p type1

    if <condition> {
        p = type2(p)
        p = type2{"1","2"}
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign struct with another struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981592/assign-struct-with-another-struct).

Comment: not a duplicate now, cannot assign type1 with type2

Comment: According to my lame understanding of go type system, p is _type1_, period. How the compiler would know what type is _p_ after the _if_ condition? The best you can do is to assign the fields.

Comment: what you are saying makes sense..didn't think about it

Comment: I convert it to an actual answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

According to my lame understanding of go type system, *p* is *type1*, period. How the compiler would know what type is *p* after the *if* condition? The best you can do is to assign the fields.